# RestSharp response is always NULL

Tags: json, restsharp

I am trying to get the authentication token from an API but authResponse is always NULL.

Below is the code I am using as well as the actual JSON response that I would expect.  Any idea why it is always NULL?

```
public static string GetAccessToken(string username, string password)
    {
        var authClient = new RestClient(authBaseURL);
        var authRequest = new RestRequest();

        var authenticationModel = "{ Email : " + username + ", Password : " + password + "}";
        authRequest.AddParameter("application/json", authenticationModel, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        var authResponse = authClient.Execute<Auth>(authRequest);
        var accessToken = authResponse.Data.AccessToken;

        return accessToken.Trim('"');
    }

//JSON response
    {
        "AccessToken": "xxxxx"
    }
```

Comment: what is the status code? you don't define any method. What does the API expect you to send? I use `request.AddJsonBody()` to send json. What does the request look like in Fiddler?

Comment: you probably need to add another header that states the grant type. Something like: request.AddParameter("grant_type", "client_credentials");